# Install npm package globally using brew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, package-managers, npm-scripts

I want to ship a CLI tools developed using NodeJs and I am trying to use yum instead of installing it globally using npm as I don't want users requirement to have Nodejs and npm installed. Not sure how to do it?

Replace

```
npm install -g my-cli-tool
```

With

```
brew install my-cli-tool
```

So users don't have to have NodeJs and Npm installed. Kind of need package the whole Nodejs runtime environment + my package as a Brew package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a homebrew formula by yourself. I'll provide some useful resources for your need.

1. Read the [Node for Formula Author Documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Node-for-Formula-Authors), especially the formula example at the end.
2. List the similar formulae using `node` as a dependency. Use these existing formulae as references.

   ```sh
   brew uses node

   # check one of them, like this "cash-cli"
   brew edit cash-cli
   ```

Here is an example

```rb
require "language/node"

class CashCli < Formula
  desc "Convert currency rates directly from your terminal"
  homepage "https://github.com/xxczaki/cash-cli"
  url "https://registry.npmjs.org/cash-cli/-/cash-cli-4.0.0.tgz"
  sha256 "c8b1d437305bc4c492cb9b85bb1b91edb5cc74fa91bd007616746c6258dae6c5"

  bottle do
    cellar :any_skip_relocation
    sha256 "c78661062dbc6e913d0f69f45af80af1f9967e50fe1eca86a95337ab16fac7ea" => :mojave
    sha256 "6b8215de6daf01c61e48bd46465be7ad9b400d4ec5ab514f5167bee787d6fa48" => :high_sierra
    sha256 "5941317cef9b92097c4b45df1e94b7b8d08e708d9813508ab3f42f55068541d3" => :sierra
  end

  depends_on "node"

  def install
    system "npm", "install", *Language::Node.std_npm_install_args(libexec)
    bin.install_symlink Dir["#{libexec}/bin/*"]
  end

  test do
    assert_match "Conversion of USD 100", shell_output("#{bin}/cash 100 USD PLN CHF")
  end
end
```

The `bottle` part should be removed in custom formulae.

At last, maintain a tap and install your formula from that tap.

- [How to Create and Maintain a Tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap)